# Global Analytics Filter for all accounts

Tags: google, analytics

I am trying to create a filter for all of my Analytics websites. I am wondering if it is currently possible to do this. 
Basically one filter to rule them all!

thanks!

Comment: Are you asking whether it is possible to filter across multiple Analytics profiles?

Comment: Is it possible to set one filter and have it apply to all of my accounts. My purpose is to block my computer by ip without having to set each website's filter. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of clarity, the word "profile" refers to a specific tracking ID (example: `UA-123456-1`) and "account" refers to a set of tracking ID's (example: `UA-123456-1` through `UA-123456-n`).

The [Filter Manager](http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/answer.py?answer=55492) allows you to apply a filter to an entire account (and all related profiles), however, if you have access to multiple accounts and you want to automate filter creation, you will need to wait* until Google provides access to create filters through the [Management API](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/mgmt/home.html).

(* Related discussion thread: [Filters?](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/community/managementApiGroup.html?place=topic/google-analytics-management-api/EPZg5U3t4zU/discussion))